# Nginx server configuration with symlinks to root folder

Tags: symbolic-link, nginx

I am developing an laravel app. I have a server configuration like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dev.site.com;
        return 301 https://dev.site.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /chain.key;
        ssl_certificate_key /private.key;

        server_name dev.site.com;

        root /home/site/backend/dev-app/current/public;
        index index.php;
        charset utf-8;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_http_version       1.1;
    gzip_disable            "MSIE [1-6].";
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_proxied            expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_comp_level         9;

    fastcgi_buffers         8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size     32k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout    180;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
            access_log      off;
            expires         max;
    }

    location / {
            index  index.html index.htm index.php; #try static .html file first
            ##try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;  <<Wrong!! this will break bundles like OneAuth for example
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page      404 /index.php;

    #set client_max_body_size
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    #set client_body_buffer_size
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-site.sock;
    }
}
```

I've configured ci/cd which downloads new version of app to the server and updates /home/site/backend/dev-app/current symlink to this new location. Command to updating symlink is:

```
ln -nfs /home/site/backend/new_release /home/site/backend/dev-app/current
```

But this update not affecting nginx. Site still working as old one. What should I do to make symbolik link affect nginx?

**UPD**

After some researching this problem, I found that nginx correctly founding folder but application itself still returning incorrect result. What that would be?

Comment: `/home/site/backend/dev-app/current/public` is listed in your Nginx configuration as the website `root` but the symlink location is listed as just `/home/site/backend/dev-app/current` in your question. Is this a typo or is there another explanation? Are you restarting Nginx after each update? Have you taken application or browser caching into consideration?

Comment: /home.../current is symlink, and inside this symlink always will be public directory. After update I'm not restarting nginx. Even if I restart it is not working.